# Hexagonal patterns when we look at bright light or sun

Tags: optics, everyday-life, diffraction, lenses

when we look at bright light or sun, we many a **times hexagonal patterns** are observed. these are easily observed when we *click their images*. why all this happens? is all this is just a **lens flare** or is it that nature favors certain pattern like *Fibonacci*.

Comment: If there were any links in your question, they have disappeared... Most likely you are seeing diffraction patterns but without seeing what you describe it's hard to be sure.

Comment: Probably lens flare. There are no hexagons when you look at the Sun with just your eyes

Comment: [link]https://www.flickr.com/photos/mrullmi/1426884913/

Comment: [link]https://photographyblogger.net/25-excellent-sun-flare-photography-examples/

Answer (score 4):

THe hexagons are diffraction patters from the aperture stop, which in some lenses comprises six leaves arranged in a way that allows the effective diameter of the lens to vary.

Comment: But why they are always hexagonal and not any other shape like pentagon or octagon?

Comment: Viewing the photo, I think the glare produced by the bright Sunlight has the geometry of a heptagon. Moreover, the diffraction "arms" from the image of the Sun lead to me to say that the diaphragm of the camera is not hexagonal. The multiple retroreflections of the illuminated diaphragm in the different lens surfaces is what causes the glare. Note also their colors that has to do with the anti reflection coatings in those surfaces.